# How to dispose a CoreServiceClient?

Tags: core-service, web8.5

What is the proper way to dispose a `CoreServiceClient` in SDL Web 8.5?

Some great Core Service posts from [2012](https://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/core-service-client-sample-code.html) and [2013](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-correctly-dispose-coreservice.html) instruct to check the state, and call `Abort()` or `Close()`. The Tridion-PowerShell-Modules project does something similar in [Close-TridionCoreServiceClient](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules/blob/master/CoreService/Client.psm1).

```
         if (_client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
            _client.Abort();
        }
        else
        {
            _client.Close();
        }
```

However, the Core Service client API has a `CoreServiceClient.Dispose()` method, which calls `ClientHelper.DisposeClient()` which does those checks already. Maybe this has changed over time, but I think the API handles this for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation for 8.5 states that there are two ways for disposal:

1. Dispose method
2. Using method

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-CB0DBEF4-3A0D-4389-BAA3-92B1B15D1D35

Comment: This is the right answer for Web 8 and later. The PowerShell modules still does it the old way, as it still supports the earlier versions (where Dispose does not abort or close correctly)